# If $p\nmid a$ (where $p$ is a prime), then prove that there is an integer $b$ such that $a\mid (p^b -1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> If $p\nmid a$ (where $p$ is a prime), then prove that there is an integer $b$ such that $a\mid (p^b -1)$ .

Though the thing seems easily verified through trivial put and check solutions, but I am not being able to get a complete solution as per required in number theory. Please help and kindly give suggestion on how I can improve my number theory...

Comment: As stated, $b=0$ is an integer that always works.  Almost certainly you are looking for a *positive* integer $b$, not just an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each of the powers $p^1$, $p^2$, $p^3$, $p^4$, and so on, *imagine* computing the remainders when $p^1$, $p^2$, $p^3$, $p^4$, and so on is divided by $a$.

There are only finitely many conceivable different remainders, so there are positive integers $k$ and $l$, with $k\lt l$, such that $p^l$ has the same remainder on division by $a$ as $p^k$.

It follows that $p^l-p^k$ is divisible by $a$, and therefore $p^k(p^{l-k}-1)$ is divisible by $a$.

However, $p^k$ is relatively prime to $a$, so $a$ must divide $p^{l-k}-1$. Set $b=l-k$, and we are finished.

Comment: Many many thanks again @Andre Nicolas. Again you solved a great deal for me.

Comment: You  are welcome.

Comment: Doesn't this use the Pigeon Hole Principle?

Comment: @Dhruv: Yes, it does use it, I did not mention the Pigeonhole Principle explicitly, because the fact that there must be (many) repetitions of remainders seems clear even if we do not give the idea a name.

Answer (score 6):

Observe that since $p\nmid a$ we can say that $\gcd(a,p)=1$. It immediately follows from [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)  that, $$p^{\varphi(a)}\equiv 1\pmod a$$ where $\varphi$ is [Euler's Totient Function](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCioTm1tjMAhWMMY8KHVvqA98QFgg7MAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEuler%27s_totient_function&usg=AFQjCNH9jLtkBKMqIKAntw1KgNa6P-k9Ng&bvm=bv.122129774,d.c2I).

Answer (score 1):

> $a|p^b-1$.

So, we can say,$p^b\equiv1\pmod a$

From Euler phi function,we get

$p^{\phi(a)}\equiv1\pmod a$ $

$[\phi(a)=\text{number of integers less than and co-prime to 'a'}]$.If $a=p_1^a\times p_2^b...p_n^z$ is the prime factorisation of $a$ then $\phi(a)=a(1-\frac{1}{p_1})(1-\frac{1}{p_2})...(1-\frac{1}{p_n})$

Comparing the two equations we get,$b=\phi(a)$

Comment: It should be $p^{\phi(a)}\equiv1\pmod a$

Comment: @maverick Thanks for catching the typo!!